# lodash фильтрация многомерного массива

Tags: lodash

Есть многомерный массив:

```
var array = [
  {
    "day":"May 23 2019",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id":1,
        "Country":"NL",
        "User": 12345
      }, {
        "Id":2,
        "Country":"RU",
        "User": 67890
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "day":"May 20 2019",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id":1,
        "Country":"NL",
        "User": 222222
      }, {
        "Id":2,
        "Country":"RU",
        "User": 333333
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

через **lodash** хочу отфильтровать пользователя `67890`

```
_.filter(array, { items: [ { User: 67890  } ]});
```

он мне вернет весь объект верхнего уровня

```
  {
    "day":"May 23 2019",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id":1,
        "Country":"NL",
        "User": 12345
      }, {
        "Id":2,
        "Country":"RU",
        "User": 67890
      }
    ]
  }
```

а я хочу чтобы он вернул (то есть чтобы в него не попадали "лишние" пользователи, чтобы в конце концов в массиве были **строго** пользователи с нужным айдишником)

```
  {
    "day":"May 23 2019",
    "items": [ {
        "Id":2,
        "Country":"RU",
        "User": 67890
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного скорректировал твой пример для показательности:

```js
var _ = require('lodash'); 

var array = [
  {
    "day":"May 23 2019",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id":1,
        "Country":"NL",
        "User": 12345
      }, {
        "Id":2,
        "Country":"RU",
        "User": 67890
      }, {
        "Id":3,
        "Country":"US",
        "User": 67890
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "day":"May 20 2019",
    "items": [
      {
        "Id":1,
        "Country":"NL",
        "User": 222222
      }, {
        "Id":2,
        "Country":"RU",
        "User": 333333
      }, {
        "Id":3,
        "Country":"US",
        "User": 67890
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Одной строкой это сделать сложновато:

```js
    const query = 67890;

    const magic = (array, query) => {
      const days = _.filter(array, { items: [ { User: query  } ]});
      return days.map(day => {
        const users = day.items.filter(el => el['User'] === query);
        return { day : day['day'], items : users };
      });
    };

    const result = magic(array, query);
```